# WiFi driver working, but missing from "Network and Internet" settings

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

On Windows 10 when the wifi adaptor is working okay, it shows up in "Network and Internet" Settings like this:
[image]

On my computer, however, it looks like this:
[image]

With the WiFi completely missing.   This is even though my TP-LINK device seems to be working okay:
[image]

If I click the network troubleshooter, it tries to reset the wireless network adaptor and fails, saying "Problems found: Problem with wireless adapter or access point": Not Fixed.

The "Wi-Fi 5" adapter shows up when the tp-link usb is plugged in:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Is it listed when you click “Change adapter options”? What does the tray icon look like? Can you connect to Wifi networks?

Comment: Does this card use an external program from the manufacturer to control rather than native windows control?

Comment: @DanielB, there is no tray icon.  I cannot connect to WiFi.   Change adapter options does not offer anything useful

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, the TP-Link adaper is supposed to use the Windows built in wireless utility, but the Windows build-in wireless utility is not working.

Comment: So, just to clarify: [This window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40dQV.png) does *not* list your Wifi adapter? In that case please [provide the output](https://superuser.com/posts/1398596/edit) of the `Get-NetAdapter | Select Name, NdisVersion` PowerShell command. Your Wifi adapter may no longer be supported by Windows.

Comment: @DanielB, when I plug in the tp-link card, the wifi-5 adapter appears, and shows in the PowerShell command you suggested.  I added the screen grab to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this problem by realizing that the network discovery service got disabled somehow.  Enabling it fixed the problem!

From [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-wont-show-available-wifi-networks/a131b6b1-c171-4a2a-896d-0bf8b41fee37): 
"
If your computer can connect to the previous WiFi networks automatically, but there are no network names showing on the network list, then this could be an issue with the network discovery. To check if this is the case, open the Control Panel, go to Network and Internet, click Network Sharing Center, and click Advanced sharing settings, then check if the Network discovery is on. If it's not, select Turn on network discovery, then click Save changes.